# Detect Vulnerabilities on hosts using nmap/zenmap

Tags: command-line, nmap, vulnerabilities

I am new in `nmap`. I wanna know is there a command for detecting high, medium or low vulnerabilities on hosts, lists number of their vulnerabilities and shows them?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`nmap` itself is not really a vulnerability scanner though it handles functions related to vulnerability detection and remediation.  `nmap` does support something called NSE (NMAP Scripting Engine) for which many people have written scripts that perform automated checks for certain vulnerabilities using `nmap`.  You could conceivably match the vulnerabilities found with a priority list, that you yourself maintain, that maps a vulnerability to a given severity level.

You are probably much better off using a framework like Metasploit for this.

Here is a nice resource, though, that explains some of the different components that might help you get to your stated goal: http://resources.infosecinstitute.com/nmap-cheat-sheet/